# Should I use PDO PARAM_LOB or PARAM_STR for MySQL TEXT type?

Tags: php, mysql, text, pdo

Should I use PDO `PARAM_LOB` or `PARAM_STR` for MySQL `TEXT` type? I expect my data to be 5000+ characters.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':notes', $notes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

OR

```
$stmt->bindParam(':notes', $notes, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

Comment: Use a LOB for TEXT and BLOB types. If you use `PARAM_STR` PHP will attempt to allocate enough memory to accommodate the max size of the object, which is 4GB in the case of LONGTEXT/LONGBLOB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be using large chunks of data, as you have mentioned in your use-case, then yes -- I would use `PDO::PARAM_LOB` to manipulate your data using data streams.

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php):

> At some point in your application, you might find that you need to
>   store "large" data in your database. Large typically means "around 4kb
>   or more", although some databases can happily handle up to 32kb before
>   data becomes "large". Large objects can be either textual or binary in
>   nature. PDO allows you to work with this large data type by using the
>   PDO::PARAM_LOB type code in your PDOStatement::bindParam() or
>   PDOStatement::bindColumn() calls. PDO::PARAM_LOB tells PDO to map the
>   data as a stream, so that you can manipulate it using the PHP Streams
>   API.

And using it like this:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select contenttype, imagedata from images where id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: $type");
fpassthru($lob);
```

Answer (score 1):

For as tiny amount of text as just 5 kilobytes it doesn't make any difference.

You may start worrying when your texts will come near  1000000 characters. As long as you don't have to deal with this amount, don't worry about that stuff at all