# Php adding images to Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, addition

I would adding images to mysql database as Blob using Php. I can adding image to mysql databases but i can't adding images.

The code :

```
$image = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

 $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php","php","");
 $adddata = $connection -> prepare("insert into images (image) value (?)");
 $adddata -> bindParam(1, $image, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

 $adddata -> execute();
```

I know there are differents ways but i would use this code.

Comment: Not an answer , but consider referring to images instead of saving them to your database.

Comment: you can upload the image and save the path as string to your database. Then on retrieval just reference the location path

Comment: @Jelman I can't. Its obligatory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724762/3635079

Comment: Try this `addslashes(file_get_contents(fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'rb')))`

Comment: @rahulpatel the code doesn't work.

Comment: Can i do with foreach

Comment: @rahulpatel The error is : Notice: Undefined index: image[] in C:\xampp\htdocs\okulue.php on line 25

Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\okulue.php on line 25

Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\okulue.php on line 25

Comment: wat is the error??

Comment: @rahulpatel      
 
The error is : Notice: Undefined index: image[] in C:\xampp\htdocs\okulue.php on line 25 Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\okulue.php on line 25 Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\okulue.php on line 25